# Oracle Database Performnace

Tags: oracle11g, load-testing, database-performance

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to Oracle Database instance running on a shared server. I want to perform load testing on the database with following load:

1. 100000 records per minute insert on table#1
2. 10000 records per minute insert on table#2
3. 1000 records per minute read on table#2

I have already generated above load but do not know how can I measure the performance of the Oracle database before and after the load. I do not have DBA privileges on the database.

I want to measure following parameters (Before and After load):

1. I/O Throughput
2. Network Latency
3. Memory utilization
4. Query execution time

I have tried using DBA functionality of SQL Developer but couldn't make any inference out of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be measuring Oracle database performance **during** the load, not "before" or "after" as this way you should be able to compare the test results, correlate performance metrics with the increasing load, etc.

If the tool you're using to create the load doesn't provide required metrics it might be a good idea to reconsider the tool as you should be able to get the required data from the load report. If you don't have anything in mind check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it is:

- free and open source
- supports Oracle (and many other) databases load testing via [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- supports setting desired requests execution rate via [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- has variety of [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) and [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) for test results analysis
- Memory Utilization (as well as other system health metrics like CPU, RAM, Disk, Swap usage, etc) can be obtained using [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)